# Form field values escaping while submit process unless form field values disabled option

Tags: extjs

I have a form with multiple fields like text box, combo box and radio with their values. I want to avoid specific text fields cannot allow for the submit function. Other than the field values disabled option idea.

Comment: can you show some of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [submitValue](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Field.html#cfg-submitValue) field config.

> Setting this to false will prevent the field from being submitted even
>   when it is not disabled.

Comment: field config **submitValue** works without disabled the field. May I know one thing all fields having this config in ext js.